# Generate a PHP array with 100 tickets and a random number to compare

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to symfony and I am trying to make a function that generates a random number and then I want to check this random number in an array of prices. Let's say there are 100 tickets so 100 items in the array. 50 of them are a price "foo" 30 "bar" and 0 "win nothing".

My goals is to populate this array at random so it should look like this:

```
array(
 1=>foo,
 2=>foo,
 3=>bar,
 4=>nothing,
 ...
)
```

EDIT
here is what i've tried but doesn't seem to be working. The array is being filled with only the last fill

```
$prices = array_fill(0, 99, '10');
$prices = array_fill(100, 139, '100');
$prices = array_fill(139, 149, '200');
$prices = array_fill(149, 150, 'reis');
($prices);
```

I have no idea how to populate my array at random and could use all the help in the world

Any help would be realy awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not a code writing service. But simple version: fill an array with your items, in order, in the quantities you want, then `shuffle()` it.

Comment: @MarcB hello thanks for your response can you checkout edited OP i forgot to add me code :)

Comment: Didn't you mean to say that 20 win "nothing"? Since 100-50-30 = 20 tickets left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be broken up into two simple parts. First, you need to create an array with an arbitrary number of values, which you could do with a function like this, as per your requirements described above.

```
function createTickets(Array $items, $totalItems) {

    $arr = [];
    // populate each item with $quantity
    foreach($items as $item => $quantity) {
        $arr = array_merge($arr, array_fill(0, $quantity, $item));
    }
    // fill in the rest with 'nothhing'
    $arr = array_merge($arr, array_fill(0, $totalItems - array_sum($items), 'nothing'));

    // return the final result
    return $arr;
}
```

So, to create an array of 100 items, with 50 `foo` and 30 `bar`, and the rest are `nothing`, you would do something like this.

```
$tickets = createTickets(['foo' => 50, 'bar' => 30], 100);
```

Second, you need to select items at random from the array you created.

The actual order of the elements in the array doesn't matter. You can use something like [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) to randomize the order of elements in the array, but that's not necessary, because you can always select items from the array at random using [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array-rand), for example.

```
// Randomly select an item from the array
$someItem = $tickets[array_rand($tickets)];
```

Becuase you already know how many items you're creating in the array, you can always supply the amount of random items to extract to `array_rand`.

```
// Select 10 items at random
foreach(array_rand($tickets, 10) as $key) {
    echo $tickets[$key], "\n"; // do something with item here
}
```

If you prefer to just shuffle the array because you intend to consume the entire array at random you could just do that instead.

```
shuffle($tickets);
foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
    // now each item is at random
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reaction I understand what you're doing here but what exactly is the $quantity in the for each loop inside your function?

Comment: I ge tthis error Warning: array_fill(): Number of elements must be positive on that line

Comment: `$quantity` signifies the number of times you want to populate the array with that string (_being the key_). Also, no you would not get that warning from my example above. You would get it if you passed an array to the function where the value was a non-numeric value or non-positive number though. Notice I'm using `['foo' => 50, 'bar' => 30]` where the key is the `string` and the value is the __number of times to add the string to the array__.